# Optimal Height of a Light Source for Maximum Illumination Given Distance and Angle of Incidence

Tags: calculus

I'm working on the following problem:

> The illumination provided on a flat surface by a light source is inversely proportional to the square of the distance from the source and. directly proportional to the sine of the angle of incidence. How high should  a light be placed on a pole to maximize the illumination on the ground 50 ft from the pole?

[image]

Let $C$ be the illumination function and $k$ the proportionality constant. We express
$C$ as $$C = \frac{k \cdot \sin(\alpha)}{d^2}$$

Given that $\sin(\alpha) = \frac{50}{d}$, we can substitute this into the equation for $C$, yielding
$$C = \frac{50k}{d^3}$$

We then take the first derivative of $C$ with respect to $d$, obtaining $$C' = -\frac{150k}{d^4}$$

I'm stuck at this point, because when setting $C'$ equal to zero, $d^4$ would need to be infinite, and thus there are no real solutions for $d$.

Comment: Since the sine is maximized when $\alpha=90°$ and the brightness is maximized when distance from the light source is the closest... Shouldn't the answer simply be $h=0$? I don't think we need to think too far. Am I missing something? 

Comment: As constructed, the answer is $h = 0$, although one wonders what the point of the question was.  Using the same formula, but the complement of the angle of incidence, you get:
Plot[Sin[h/Sqrt[50+h^2]]/(h^2+50^2),{h,0,100}] (put that in Wolfram Alpha), which clearly has a maximum at a non-zero value of $h$ and shows the illumination tending to zero as $h \rightarrow 0$.  Perhaps there is an error in the wording of the problem.